# CakePHP 4 validation upload file extension

Tags: cakephp

I added validation extension file upload code in CakePHP 4 to model:

```
$validator->notEmpty('zones_file', 'Please choose file to upload');
    
$validator->add('zones_file', 'validExtension', [
        'rule' => ['extension', ['csv']],
        'message' => 'Please choose file with extension csv'
]);
```

Template file is:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($posts, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('postcode', ['type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Post code:'])?>
<?= $this->Form->control('total_order_amount', ['type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Total order amount:'])?>
<?=$this->Form->control('long_product', ['type' => 'checkbox']);?>
<?=$this->Form->control('zones_file', ['type' => 'file', 'label' => 'CSV file with zones'])?>
<?=$this->Form->submit('Save');?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

If uploaded file has extension other than *.csv than no error is shown. What code should I use to validate file uploaded extension ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$validator
->notEmpty('zones_file', 'Please choose file to upload');
->add('zones_file', [
'validExtension' => [
'rule' => ['extension',['text/csv']],
'message' => __('Please choose file with extension csv')]
]);
```

Try this!

- https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/validation.html

Comment: I tried this code but when uploaded file has other extension than *.csv error is not shown.

Comment: Share the controller

Comment: What code to use and what file to share the controller ?

Comment: If share the controller is insert in model code `use App\Controller;` it will not work.